# Selecting Specific Vertices to Edit

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

[image]

Is there any way to choose certain vertices to edit and move?

I want to work in *Wireframe View* and move only certain vertices. For example, I only want to work with the vertices shown in the above edge loop. However, eventually these edges will overlap with other edges and I lose track of which vertex belongs to which edge loop.

Is there a way to edit ONLY these vertices or at least keep track of them?

Comment: maybe create a vertex group?

Comment: read about vertex groups on the blender manual https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/vertex_groups/vertex_groups.html

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on [Noidea](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/27959/noidea)'s comment, *Vertex Groups* probably are the most simple option. Here's what you can do to create a *Vertex Group*:

1. Select the vertices that you will want to be able to easily select later.
2. Go to the *Properties panel > Object Data tab > Vertex Groups dropdown*.
3. Add a new *Vertex Group* with the plus button.

[image]

4. Double click on *Group* to rename it and name it something that will signify which vertices you are grouping. I named mine **End Cap**.

[image]

5. Make sure that the *Weight:* value is set to *1* and click *Assign*.

Now, anytime that you want to select those vertices, click *Select*. You can add as many *Vertex Groups* as you want. In a demo I built, I used *Vertex Groups* **End Cap** and **Loop Cut** (for the loop cut on top of the end cap, useful if adding subsurf, for example). Watch how I can easily integrate those two *Vertex Groups* into my workflow of nothingness.

[image]